# Visualisations created in the pandas library to be outputted in flask application

Tags: python, pandas, flask, web-applications

Can anyone explain why this flask application keeps terminating in my localhost due to an uncaught error?

I am trying to create an app that will take in putted csv file (all files have the same columns and the form is in the template mentioned), and then output visualisations such as 'nat'. However something seems to be going really wrong!! Help!!

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/tadadata.html')
def form():
    return render_template('tadadata.html')

@app.route('/main_program', methods=["POST"])
def main_program_view():

    # Input file
    file = request.files['input_file']
    if not file:
        return "No file"

    # Put input file in dataframe
    tourism_df = pd.read_csv(file)

    #get relevant data  
    relevantdata = tourism_df.drop(columns=['Booked', 'Property name', 'Promotion code', 'Guest first name', 'Guest last name', 'Guest email', 'Guest phone number', 'Guest organisation', 'Guest address', 'Guest address2', 'Guest state', 'Guest post code', 'Check in date', 'Check out date', 'Arrival time', 'Guest comments', 'Requested newsletter', 'Status', 'Rate plans', 'Subtotal amount', 'Extra adult amount', 'Extra child amount' ,'Extra infant amount', 'Extras total amount', 'Credit card surcharge processed amount', 'Surcharge Percentage', 'Promotional Discount', 'Payment total', 'Payment Received', 'Number of adults', 'Number of children', 'Guest city', 'Number of infants', 'Number of Rooms', 'Custom Property Specific Data', 'Referral' ,'Payments deposit processed total', 'Payment outstanding', 'Mobile booking?', 'Promotion Description', 'Enter rates including fees', 'Fixed Taxes Total', 'Percentage Taxes Total', 'Rooms'])

    nationalities = relevantdata['Guest country'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

    nat = nationalities.plot.bar() 
    plt.ylabel('Percentage') 
    plt.title('Nationality')

    return nat()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```